# Getting specific value from JSON in php from UPCitemdb API

Tags: php, json

I am trying to only one attribute-value pair called title.

This is a sample code from  the website and it returns the whole JSON data. How do I get it to just return title and then store it as a string variable in php?

```
 <<?php
$user_key = 'only_for_dev_or_pro';
$endpoint = 'https://api.upcitemdb.com/prod/trial/lookup';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(

));

// HTTP GET
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint.'?upc=4002293401102');
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ($httpcode != 200)
  echo "error status $httpcode...\n";
else 
  echo $response."\n";
/* if you need to run more queries, do them in the same connection.
* use rawurlencode() instead of URLEncode(), if you set search string
 * as url query param
 */
sleep(2);
// proceed with other queries
curl_close($ch);
```

JSON:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: openresty/1.9.7.4 Date: Fri, 14 Apr 2017 14:33:27 GMT Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Content-Length: 2986 Connection: keep-alive X-Powered-By: Express X-RateLimit-Limit: 100 X-RateLimit-Reset: 1492263082 X-RateLimit-Remaining: 87 ETag: W/"baa-nUP5zq4A0eSpWOkpnkUZVg" Vary: Accept-Encoding Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.upcitemdb.com Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,Accept Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Type,X-RateLimit-Remaining,X-RateLimit-Limit,X-RateLimit-Reset,total,offset {"code":"OK","total":1,"offset":0,"items":[{"ean":"4002293401102","title":"Wusthof Gourmet 3-Inch Serrated Paring Knife","description":"A Wusthof Gourmet stamped knife is great for newer cooks or for use in a second home. These value priced knives are quite sharp. Thanks to their high-carbon stainless steel, their sharp edge is long lasting. Triple riveted handles are extremely durable. Hand wash only. Lifetime warranty from Wusthof with normal use and proper care. Made in Solingen Germany.","brand":"W?sthof","model":"4011-7","color":"Multi","size":"","dimension":"8 X 1X 1 inches","weight":"0.1 Pounds","currency":"","lowest_recorded_price":12.99,"images":["http://www.chefscatalog.com/img/products/500x500/99528_500.jpg","http://img1.r10.io/PIC/84707643/0/1/250/84707643.jpg","http://c.shld.net/rpx/i/s/pi/mp/33108/2456981411?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chefscatalog.com%2Fimg%2Fproducts%2F1000x1000%2F99528_1000.jpg&d=8ba15ee3bfc8785ae78e62c3c0762bcb86214ed4","http://images10.newegg.com/ProductImageCompressAll200/A0NV_1_20120523_5340513.jpg","http://images.prosperentcdn.com/images/250x250/cdn.metrokitchen.com/images/uploads/wu-4011-zoomed.jpg"],"offers":[{"merchant":"MetroKitchen","domain":"metrokitchen.com","title":"Wusthof Gourmet 3 inch Serrated Paring Knife","currency":"","list_price":"","price":19.95,"shipping":"","condition":"New","availability":"","link":"http://www.upcitemdb.com/norob/alink/?id=y2x203y2x26384&tid=1&seq=1492180407&plt=8e28d8273c644252688700da99d3ae40","updated_t":1466567204},{"merchant":"Newegg.com","domain":"newegg.com","title":"Wusthof Gourmet - 3\" Serrated Utility Knife","currency":"","list_price":"","price":15.95,"shipping":"5.95","condition":"New","availability":"","link":"http://www.upcitemdb.com/norob/alink/?id=v2t2z2u2v2x2c4a4&tid=1&seq=1492180407&plt=353d82b7403f611d0a99d3a14c1aeba2","updated_t":1481154945},{"merchant":"Sears","domain":"sears.com","title":"Wusthof Gourmet 3-in. Serrated Paring Knife","currency":"","list_price":"","price":19.95,"shipping":"","condition":"New","availability":"","link":"http://www.upcitemdb.com/norob/alink/?id=u2p2631343x2a4d4x2&tid=1&seq=1492180407&plt=47ce957e7b574db04285b40e11ed5816","updated_t":1425619323},{"merchant":"Rakuten(Buy.com)","domain":"rakuten.com","title":"Wusthof Gourmet - 3 Serrated Utility Knife","currency":"","list_price":"","price":19.95,"shipping":"8.95","condition":"New","availability":"","link":"http://www.upcitemdb.com/norob/alink/?id=w2v233w21303c444&tid=1&seq=1492180407&plt=57e9f7ffdcf388e9c3c4e81403c0ddc9","updated_t":1476903025},{"merchant":"Chefs Catalog","domain":"chefscatalog.com","title":"Wusthof Gourmet 3-in. Serrated Paring Knife - Wusthof Gourmet","currency":"","list_price":26,"price":15.95,"shipping":"Free Shipping","condition":"New","availability":"","link":"http://www.upcitemdb.com/norob/alink/?id=u2o243z2w203b454s2&tid=1&seq=1492180407&plt=b3a67678a759c8e8d949c4e7b26d0207","updated_t":1448989675}],"asin":"B0000DJYE3","elid":"192088094351"}]}

Comment: can you share your `json`?

Comment: @SahilGulati updated

Comment: There are no. of keys with name title. which one you want? for items or for offers?

Comment: @SahilGulati "title":"Wusthof Gourmet 3-Inch Serrated Paring Knife"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and you should use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);` to prevent returning headers in curl response.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$user_key = 'only_for_dev_or_pro';
$endpoint = 'https://api.upcitemdb.com/prod/trial/lookup';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(

));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint.'?upc=4002293401102');
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ($httpcode != 200)
  echo "error status $httpcode...\n";
else 
//  echo $response."\n";

/* if you need to run more queries, do them in the same connection.
* use rawurlencode() instead of URLEncode(), if you set search string
 * as url query param
 */
sleep(2);
// proceed with other queries
curl_close($ch);

$result=json_decode($response,true);
echo $title=$result['items'][0]["title"];
```

Comment: nothing gets printed

Comment: @thenoob have you tried the demo from my post

Comment: the demo works but you have stored it manually into $response so maybe that's why it works in the demo?

Comment: @thenoob No issues i will give complete code.

Comment: @thenoob checkout this complete code . i have updated my post. Can you please check and revert. I have commented that line which was echoing your response

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for json_decode

[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) creates an object with a json string

$obj = json_decode($response);

$example = $obj->yourAttribute;

foreach($obj->items as $item)
   $title = $item->title;

Comment: How do I get it to show one attribute-value pair called title instead of the whole thing?